# my sudo apt update doesn't work

Tags: apt

I'm a complete beginner to ubuntu and i've just downloaded ubuntu 20.04 as virtual machine to run ROS on my computer. But when i tried to test it, it gave me the following log filled by errors. My computer already has a ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine and it works fine. Does the problem come from here? If not, how to fix it? Somebody please help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMi2I.png)